# Correct transition of subviews in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using a layoutToLayout navigation transition (`useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions`), but   the animation is not fluid; the subviews of the cells jump weirdly around during transition:

[image]

what could possibly be wrong?

My collectionviewcell class looks like this:

```
private class PageCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    var viewController : UIViewController? {
        willSet {
            for view in self.contentView.subviews as [UIView] {
                view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }

        didSet {
            if let view = viewController?.view {
                view.frame = self.contentView.bounds
                self.contentView.addSubview(view)
                self.contentView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleHeight | .FlexibleWidth;
                view.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleHeight | .FlexibleWidth;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by using `TLTransitionLayout` for transitioning to the other layout. It makes the animation look better for more complex cells, because it is not using Core Animation.

The approach is also compatible to `useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions`, so you get all the nice stuff like a new navigation item pushed to the navigation bar etc. (I only tested on iOS8 though).

So these were my steps:

#### 1. have a layoutToLayout transition from one UICollectionViewController to another:

---

```
DetailViewController *detail = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
detail.useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

...somewhere else in the UICollectionViewController subclass....

```
- (UICollectionViewTransitionLayout *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView transitionLayoutForOldLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)fromLayout newLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)toLayout
{
    NSArray *supplementaryKinds = @[]; // optional supplementary view kinds
    TLTransitionLayout *layout = [[TLTransitionLayout alloc] initWithCurrentLayout:fromLayout nextLayout:toLayout supplementaryKinds:supplementaryKinds];
    return layout;
}
```

---

#### 2. have a `UINavigationControllerDelegate` somewhere implementing this method:

---

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                                  animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                               fromViewController:(UIViewController*)fromVC
                                                 toViewController:(UIViewController*)toVC
{
    if (operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPush) {
        return [[PushLayoutToLayoutAnimator alloc] init];
    }

    if (operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPop) {
        return [[PopLayoutToLayoutAnimator alloc] init];
    }
    
    return nil;
}
```

---

#### 3. implement the animators:

---

```
#import "TTProfileDetailPushAnimator.h"
#import <TLTransitionLayout.h>

@implementation TTProfileDetailPushAnimator

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    return 0.5;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UICollectionViewController *toViewController;
    toViewController = (UICollectionViewController *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    NSAssert([toViewController isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewController class]], @"must be collection view controller");
    NSAssert(toViewController.useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions, @"expecting layoutToLayout transition!");

    [[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:toViewController.view];

    UICollectionViewLayout *toLayout = toViewController.collectionViewLayout;
    UICollectionView *toCollectionView = toViewController.collectionView;
    NSTimeInterval duration = [self transitionDuration:transitionContext];
    
    UICollectionViewLayoutInteractiveTransitionCompletion completionBlock = ^(BOOL completed, BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
    };

    TLTransitionLayout *layout;
    layout = (TLTransitionLayout *)[toCollectionView transitionToCollectionViewLayout:toLayout
                                                                             duration:duration
                                                                               easing:CubicEaseInOut
                                                                           completion:completionBlock];

    CGPoint toOffset = [toCollectionView toContentOffsetForLayout:layout
                                                       indexPaths:[toCollectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]
                                                        placement:TLTransitionLayoutIndexPathPlacementCenter];
    
    layout.toContentOffset = toOffset;
}


@end
```

---

```
#import "TTProfileDetailPopAnimator.h"
#import <TLTransitionLayout.h>

@implementation TTProfileDetailPopAnimator

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    return 0.5;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UICollectionViewController* toViewController;
    toViewController = (UICollectionViewController *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UICollectionViewController* fromViewController;
    fromViewController = (UICollectionViewController *)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    
    NSAssert([toViewController isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewController class]], @"toVC must be collection view controller");
    NSAssert([fromViewController isKindOfClass:[UICollectionViewController class]], @"fromVC must be collection view controller");
    NSAssert(fromViewController.useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions, @"expecting layoutToLayout transition!");

    [[transitionContext containerView] insertSubview:toViewController.view aboveSubview:fromViewController.view];
    
    UICollectionViewLayout *toLayout = toViewController.collectionViewLayout;
    UICollectionView *toCollectionView = toViewController.collectionView;
    NSTimeInterval duration = [self transitionDuration:transitionContext];
    
    UICollectionViewLayoutInteractiveTransitionCompletion completionBlock = ^(BOOL completed, BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
    };
    
    TLTransitionLayout *layout;
    layout = (TLTransitionLayout *)[toCollectionView transitionToCollectionViewLayout:toLayout
                                                                             duration:duration
                                                                               easing:CubicEaseInOut
                                                                           completion:completionBlock];

    CGPoint toOffset = [toCollectionView toContentOffsetForLayout:layout
                                                       indexPaths:[toCollectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]
                                                        placement:TLTransitionLayoutIndexPathPlacementCenter];
    layout.toContentOffset = toOffset;
}

@end
```

Comment: this seems like an awesome solution. Do you have a project where this is working? And can you still use autolayout for the subviews of the cell?

Comment: @BobdeGraaf yes this is working in my app "Inkmonkey" https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/inkmonkey-the-tattoo-network/id955331288 (in the user profile screen). My cells contain UIViewController views.

Comment: There are two downsides I noticed: the `TLTransitionLayout` crashes sometimes (very very rarely) for some reason I could not figure out yet why. Also adding a a big view hierarchy like a UIViewController view as a subview to a UICollectionViewCell is very heavy for UIKit and can make the app feel very unresponsive on old devices. Iphone6 and 6+ handle it very well though.

Comment: Yes, I'm also using autolayout

Comment: stefreak, using your exact code the push animator works perfectly but the pop animation code always crashes, any idea why? Also you say you use autolayout. So I assume somewhere you animate the constraints? Could you point me in the right direction (or provide some code) where exactly I need to animate the autolayout constraints of the subviews of my collectionviewcell? :)

Comment: stefreak, alright I've fixed the pop transition crash, I forgot to put the transitionLayoutForOldLayout method in the second collectionviewcontroller. I still don't know where the code goes for animating specific subviews of my collectionview though :)

Comment: Ah do you want to animate the contents of the cell to get smaller / use a different layout in the smaller state?

Comment: What I did is actually just shrinked down the views in the small state setting the scale in `- (void)applyLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes;` (you can override that in the cell and get a callback for every frame of the animation) ... I can imagine that you could adjust constants of your NSLayoutConstraints there too (but dont add or remove constraints because that would have a big performance penalty)

Comment: If it works for you I would be very happy if you could upvote my posts =)

Comment: The thing is using `TLTransitionLayout` you cant use UIView animate because TLTransitionLayout is using/hacking the interactive ViewController transition feature for more control over the transition

Comment: stefreak you're right that methods is called at each point in the animation! But I don't have the progress though with this. Of course if I know the size I can calculate the progress. But what I actually did get working just before you commented was using TLTransitionsLayout's setUpdateLayoutAttributes method. This also returns the progress which is even more helpful for me :) So I've added a completion block to the animators which return the indexpaths & progress and use that to animate subviews. I think I've got a good solution right now, thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad that my lonely post here helped someone :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112037/discussion-between-bob-de-graaf-and-stefreak).